# Symfony2 DB2 doctrine: Could not create database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, db2, symfony-2.7

If I want to create my database-structur in DB2 docrine response:

```
>php app/console doctrine:database:create
Could not create database "monng" for connection named default
Notice: Undefined index: dbname
```

But creating an entity from DB (read/write to DB2) is possible:

```
>php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AppBundle
Importing mapping information from "default" entity manager
  > writing /var/www/html/structure/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Projects.orm.xml
```

Also created a frontend via CRUD and I have no problems - can write/edit/delete items.

parameter.yml:

```
parameters:
    database_host: 172.25.x.y
    database_port: '60000'
    database_name: structure
    database_user: structure
    database_password: xxxxxxx
    database_driver: ibm_db2
```

config.yml:

```
...
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
...
```

Do you have and ideas?

```
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             1.6.2   Symfony DoctrineBundle
```

**EDIT**
Did some further research:

```
[_params:Doctrine\DBAL\Connection:private] => Array
        (
            [driver] => ibm_db2
            [host] => 172.25.75.10
            [port] => 60000
            [user] => monng
            [password] => monng
            [charset] => UTF8
            [driverOptions] => Array
                (
                )

            [defaultTableOptions] => Array
                (
                )

        )
```

Comment: Where did you put this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to be simple:

just use "doctrine:schema:create" instead of "doctrine:database:create" for DB2-Connect

Answer (score -1):

you can try to remove quotes on database_port. Else maybe the user structure for database have no right for creating ?

Comment: Still the same "error" when I removed the quotes - the quotes have been place by the symfony-configurator (config.php)